# How do I trigger reachability in iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone

As we all have seen that the iPhone X is gorgeous with all its bezel less design and no home button. But it adds to the question of how do I go about reachability? There is no home button on it right, I can’t double tap on it now. The screen is big and how can one reach the top of the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### iPhone X now supports Reachability

Just pull down on the bottom indicator to activate Reachability after turning it on. Also note that Reachability works with Control Center access so you don't have to reach that top of your phone to get to Control Center.

To turn on Reachability: `Settings > General > Accessibility > Reachability`

Source: Rene Ritchie's [review](https://www.imore.com/iphone-x-review).

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the feature has been removed.

> No “Reachability Mode” on #iPhoneX. The smaller casing and other optimizations make it easier to manage without.

Rene Ritchie on Twitter https://twitter.com/reneritchie/status/907734708397551616

Comment: This was totally true for a short window of time...